# Error ad not found in APPODEAL Android

Tags: android, ads

When post an ad several Toast appear as they see me down here and I think it would be very annoying that users will see this inopportune Toast. as I can remove it? [image with Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isyWw.png) [other image with Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTaeA.png)

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Are you using a third party library? Does it misbehave? Did you report this problem to the maintainers of that library?

Comment: I am using SDK of APPODEAL but when I load the app appear those Toast

Answer (score 0):

Try to make 'Clean Project' and 'Rebuild Project'.

Answer (score 0):

Place the manifest, make appodeal within making application and erase the part that will not USE these:

```
Appodeal.initialize (ie, AppKey, Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL | Appodeal.SKIPPABLE_VIDEO | Appodeal.BANNER | Appodeal.MREC | Appodeal.NATIVE | Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);
```